# Pass conditional options to documentclass

Tags: beamer, conditionals, document-classes

I'd like to pass options to `\documentclass` basing on the compiler it runs, something in the lines

`\documentclass[if latex then use dvipdfm else nothing]{beamer}`

My motivation is that there're several people who can compile a certain project with their own preferences for workflow. If we use `pdflatex`, then we don't need any options for beamer, but if we want to use `latex+dvipdfm`, then we need to pass `dvipdfm` option to beamer to show everything correctly.

Is there a way to implement this? Any ideas will be welcome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Admittedly without having tried, the following should work:

```
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
\documentclass{beamer}
\else
\documentclass[dvipdfm]{beamer}
\fi
```