# Conditional compilation within documentclass option?

Tags: conditionals, optional-arguments, documentclass

This works fine and produces letter-size PDF.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[\ifdefined\afive a5paper \fi]{geometry}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
commodo consequat.
\end{document}
```

But this one does not work fine.

```
\documentclass[\ifdefined\afive a5paper \fi]{article}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
commodo consequat.
\end{document}
```

It causes error like this.

```
(./foo.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
! Extra \else.
\@fileswith@pti@ns ... #3[{#2}][{#4}]#1}\fi \else 
                                                  \def \reserved@b ##1,{\ifx...
l.2 \begin
          {document}
?
```

What went wrong here? What can I do to fix this conditional compilation within an option?

I have seen [Pass conditional options to documentclass](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155257/18587). It does not address my question because it does not explain why the error occurs in the first place. It provides a workaround by avoiding conditional compilation in documentclass option but it does not say if and how conditional compilation in documentclass option is possible.

Comment: Try with `\expandafter\documentclass\expandafter[..]{...}`.

Comment: @Werner With `\expandafter\documentclass\expandafter[\ifdefined\afive a5paper \fi]{article}`, the above code compiles. But now this code does not compile: `\def\afive{} \expandafter\documentclass\expandafter[\ifdefined\afive a5paper \fi]{article}`. Error: `! Too many }'s.`

Comment: Don't do it. The documentclass option is passed through \edef and tests and this is rather fragile. It is a bad place for clever code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If you can write this as an answer, I can accept your answer and resolve this question.